# jQuery validate success indicator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Ok, I think I have this wrong...but I cant seem to get the answer.  Im just trying to create a success checkmark or indicator that what the user has entered into the input form is valid.  The commented out portion of the script is the idea of what Im trying to achieve.  Here is the script:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
           a: {required:true, minlength:2},
           b: {required:true}
        },      
        messages: {
           a: {required: "enter your name!"},
           b: {required: "enter the date!"}                        
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.attr('name') == 'a'){
             $('#name').html(error);                
         }
         if(element.attr('name') == 'b'){
             $('#date').html(error);                
         }
        },
        success: function(error){
            //a: {$('#name').html('nice name!');},
            //b: {$('#date').html('nice date!');}                           
        },
        debug:true
    });
    $('#a').blur(function(){
        $("form").validate().element("#a");
    });
});
```

And here is the html:

```
<form action="#" id='commentForm'>
    <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
    <input type="text" name="b" id="b">
    <button type="submit">Validate!</button>
<div id="date" style="border:1px solid blue;"></div>
<div id="name" style="border:1px solid red;"></div>
</form>
```

Last, but not least, here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmw562/wQxQ8/8/

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The following link will help you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831680/how-to-display-unique-success-messages-on-jquery-form-validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part inside `success:` would be a class name or a JavaScript callback function, which looks just like any other function.  But instead, you wrote it like an array of plugin options.  Also, since it's called "success", why would `error` be passed into it when there wouldn't be any?  [As per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) it should look something like this...

```
success: function(label){
    label.addClass("valid").text("Ok!");                        
},
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

> If specified, the error label is displayed to show a valid element. If
>   a String is given, its added as a class to the label. If a Function is
>   given, its called with the label (as a jQuery object) as its only
>   argument. That can be used to add a text like "ok!".

Here is your jsFiddle slightly modified to show the basic concept.  Perhaps you can use a checkmark as a `background-image` in the CSS of the `.valid` `class`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wQxQ8/12/

Comment: Thank you Sparky!  How would I trigger an event (like making the submit button active) once all the fields are valid?

Comment: @SagarPanchal, if you have a new question about this plugin, please post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
           a: {required:true, minlength:2},
           b: {required:true}
        },      
        messages: {
           a: {required: "enter your name!"},
           b: {required: "enter the date!"}                        
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.attr('name') == 'a'){
             $('#name').html(error);                
         }
         if(element.attr('name') == 'b'){
             $('#date').html(error);                
         }
        },
        success: function(label) {
            var parentId = $(label).parent().attr("id");
            switch(parentId) {
                case "name":
                    $(label).html("nice name");
                    break;
                case "date":
                    $(label).html("nice date");
                    break;
            }                    
        },
        debug:true
    });
    $('#a').blur(function(){
        $("form").validate().element("#a");
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wQxQ8/13/

Comment: Thank you very much Candide!  It works...and it also shows me another way of doing this.  I sure appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the title, Not your actual question:

This is how to check if JQuery validation for a certain input is success or fail, It returns true / false boolean values :

```
$("[name='ConfirmCode']").valid(); // RETURNS true/false
```

example:

```
if (!$("[name='ConfirmCode']").valid())
   return;
```

To check the validation status for the entire form use:

```
$('form').valid(); // RETURNS true/false
```

To include the hidden inputs in the validation process results:

```
$('form').validate({
   ignore: []
});
```